# Почему не парсится RSS

Tags: javascript, html, парсер, расширения

Решил сделать на основе вот этого [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIP0Uz1xqoU) расширение парсер. Сделал, но оно выдает ошибку. Почему не работает парсер Расширение для Хром?
Выдает ошибку

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://www.feedrapp.info/?callback=jQuery34105091845112378484_1568141475155&q=http%3A%2F%2Fvestirama.ru%2Fserver%2Fyandex.rss&_=1568141475156'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note
>   that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used
>   as a fallback.

Этот путь `http://www.feedrapp.info` он прописан в файле `jquery.rss.js`
Файл Манифест

```
{
"name" :"Новости",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" :"Последние новости Оренбуржья",
"permissions": [
  "cookies",
  "background",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "storage",
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
"icons": { "128": "images/icon.png" },
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://vestirama.ru/*","http://vestirama.ru/server/yandex.rss" ],
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js","moment.min.js","jquery.rss.js","jquery.rss.min.js","script.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "styles/*",
    "fonts/*"
],

"browser_action" :
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Новости ВестиРама"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Новости ВЕСТИРАМА</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylescheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
      <div id="rss"></div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.rss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.rss.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$('#rss').rss("http://vestirama.ru/server/yandex.rss");
```

Оригинальные пути скриптов

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-rss/3.3.0/jquery.rss.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-rss/3.3.0/jquery.rss.min.js
```

Comment: Так вы текст ошибки прочитали?

Comment: @Alexey Ten прочитал, ничего не понял

Comment: @Alexey Ten Я не знаю как это исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас, потенциально, неправильно описаны разрешения для URL:

> "http://*/*"
>
> "https://*/*"

Попробуйте заменить на:

> `"<all_urls>"`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка связана с `CSP` - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Попробуйте в манифесте прописать

```
// Добавляем доверенный домен feedapp.info
"content_security_policy": "self' *feedapp.info blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource"
```

Тут есть больше примеров: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: Ошибка все равно присутствует